# PhoneGap and OnsenUI modal not showing up when event is fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I have an application where I can click on list items, and take action on them. The on-click event brings up a dialog box where the user is asked whether they're sure if they want to take action. 
Upon clicking OK, a modal should show up with a rotating gear icon and disappear when everything is done.

It works flawlessly if I try it in my browser, but the PhoneGap emulator on my iPhone or android is not displaying it.

I have the following modal in my index.html file:

```
<ons-modal var="modal_update">
    <ons-icon size="35px" spin="true" icon="ion-load-d"></ons-icon>
    <br><br>
    Please wait
    <br>Updating data on the server...
</ons-modal>
```

I have an on-click event, that brings up an onsen dialogbox with OK and CANCEL as possible answers.
If the users clicks on the OK, the modal should show up, and it should hide when everything is done. There's also an icon next to the list item, that should turn into a rotating gear...

So I have the following code:

```
$scope.confirm = function(item, id) {
    ons.notification.confirm({
        title:"",
        message: "Do you want to set this task to completed?",
        callback: function(idx) {
            switch(idx) {
                case 0: //if they hit CANEL
                    break;
                case 1: //if they hit OK
                    modal_update.show();
                    //PROCESSING DATA
                    //do things with the data
                    //Change icon to rotating gear 
                    //$scope.apply - i tried with and without this, nothing helped.
                    modal.hide();
                    break;
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

The modal .show() & .hide() is working in other places, like a "Pull down to refresh".

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see there is that you are not using `$scope` to access the modal and you are using `modal.hide()` instead of `modal_update.hide()`:

```
case 1: //if they hit OK
    $scope.modal_update.show();
    //PROCESSING DATA
    //do things with the data
    $scope.modal_update.hide();
    break;
```

It's working in this Codepen (I just added a timeout to see the modal): http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/KdzwGR

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, but it's not working. It's showing up in firefox and chrome, but on the phone, I cannot see the modal, nor the spinning icon next to the list item that I clicked on.